# Unintended string conversion to Hexadecimal

Tags: mysql, sql, string, view, hex

I have a formula setup that takes an decimal, that is a of radix 10 `3.6 three hours and point 6 minutes` and converts the decminal place to radix of 60 `36 minutes`. Then it round up the minutes to the nearest increment of 15 minutes using ceiling so it always rounds up `36 to 45 minutes`. Then it concats the hour part with the minute part and places a string colon between them. This sql is executed in a view.

Now in the view its comes out as a hexadecimal value instead of a string value `8:30 turns into 0x383A333020483A4D`. But in a select query it is in the right concated string format. What is going on?

```
CONCAT((((CEILING(((60 * ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1)) / 15)) * 15) / 60) + ((agent_logins.hours_worked) - ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1))) - (((CEILING(((60 * ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1)) / 15)) * 15) / 60) + ((agent_logins.hours_worked) - ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1))) % 1, ':', (((CEILING(((60 * ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1)) / 15)) * 15) / 60) + ((agent_logins.hours_worked) - ((agent_logins.hours_worked) % 1))) % 1 * 60) as hours_worked
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> If the arguments include any binary strings, the result is a binary string. A numeric argument is converted to its equivalent string form. This is a nonbinary string as of MySQL 5.5.3. Before 5.5.3, it is a binary string; to to avoid that and produce a nonbinary string, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:
>
> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
> ```

You must be using a version of MySQL prior to 5.5.3, so the numeric arguments to `CONCAT()` are converted to binary strings (resulting in a binary string overall).  Your client is displaying binary columns to you in hexadecimal form, which is a reasonable behaviour.

As the documentation says (and as suggested in [@SofianeM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13870314)), you can overcome this by explicitly casting back to a non-binary string with [`CONVERT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) or [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

However, why not simply use [`SEC_TO_TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time)?

```sql
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(CEILING(4 * hours_worked) * 900)
FROM   agent_logins
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/4998/0).

Answer (score 1):

The first four bytes of that hexadecimal representation does appear to represent the ASCII encoding of your expected string value `'8:30'`. The next four bytes appear to the ASCII encoding representing `' H:M'`.

```
0x38 = '8'
0x3A = ':'
0x33 = '3'
0x30 = '0'
0x20 = ' '
0x48 = 'H'
0x3A = ':'
0x4D = 'M'
```

---

This doesn't really answer the question you asked, but...

Why aren't you making use of the MySQL builtin functions for doing this type of formatting?  (One possible explanation is that the "duration" values you need to work with exceed the limits allowed by the MySQL `TIME` datatype i.e. -838:59:59 to 838:59:59.)

Otherwise, you could use a somewhat simpler expression to round the time up to the nearest 15 minute boundary, and format that as a string representation of hours:minutes

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(CEILING( agent_login.hours_worked *4)*900),'%k:%i')
```

### [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/220d8/3)

---

It's not at all clear why a SELECT statement using the view as a row source would be returning eight characters, when the string generated by the SELECT should be only four characters, or why the client would be choosing to display a hexadecimal representation. (Eight bytes does happen to be the length of a `BIGINT`.)

Answer (score 0):

`Convert(exp, type)` solves this problem. [Conversions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).